# Is this a bug or any limitation in filterpane plugin..?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using grails 2.2.1 , filterpane 2.3.1, we ran into a problem when we applied a filterPane to a list.gsp view with domain parameters.

Everything seems to work fine untill when we tried to add dateCreated (Date) & lastUpdated (Date) as search parameters in filterpane only dateCreated seems to shown, no matter any changes in filterPane settings in gsp doesnt yield any result for lastUpdated parameter.

Cant we able to search based on dateCreated& lastUpdated parameters which are of Date data types in domain class..

Is this a bug or any limitation in filterpane plugin..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default behavior from the filterpane plugin.  The id, version and lastUpdated properties are excluded unless you explicitly allow them using the `additionalProperties` attribute on the filterPane tag.

See http://grails-plugin-consortium.github.io/grails-filterpane/docs/guide/reference.html#filterpane